# Como editar dados cadastrados de modo que ao selecionar o cadastro a ser alterado, os dados do mesmo apareçam no mesmo formulário que foi criado?

Tags: php, mysql

Dado o seguinte formulário:

```html
<form action="action_page.php">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal information:</legend>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
    Senha:<br>
    <input type="password" name="senha" value="Senha"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Como eu poderia recuperar os dados inseridos pelo usuário, e lança-lo neste mesmo formulário ? Por exemplo, o usuário faz o cadastro, esse dados vão para o banco de dados, e então eu possuo uma página de administrador onde são apresentados todos os usuários cadastrados (até ai blz), então para cada usuário eu teria as opções de excluir, editar, sendo que ao clicar em editar a tela apresentada seja a do formulário acima porém com os dados do usuário a serem alterados ? É tipo um CRUD(eu acho) só que estou meio (para não dizer totalmente) perdido...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa uma chamada pra definir a função (se vai ser Editar, Inserir, etc).
Vamos simular pelo $_GET.

Exemplo:
Na página dados.php tu vais receber pela URL

```
    dados.php?funcao=Editar&id=2


    if($_GET['funcao'] == "Editar"){
    // Aqui tu faz a chamada do banco de dados usando o ID que também veio pelo GET (pode ser da forma que quiseres)

    Com as variáveis já definidas pelo BD é só mudar os values dos inputs.

<form action="action_page.php">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal information:</legend>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $linha['campo_tabela_first_name'];?>"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $linha['campo_tabela_last_name'];?>"><br><br>
    Senha:<br>
    <input type="password" name="senha" value="Senha"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```